# Can Hypertable remove multiple rows?

Tags: hypertable

How can I remove multiple rows in one query in hypertable?
It seems that delete doesn't do so and I read something about compact command, but it seems that it's not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, thats not yet implemented. You have to delete row by row. The COMPACT command does not have anything to do with that.